# Converting a datetime column to a string column

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to convert a datetime column back to a string in Pandas dataframe.

the syntax I have so far is:

```
all_data['Order Day new'] = dt.date.strftime(all_data['Order Day new'], '%d/%m/%Y')
```

but this returns the error:

descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'Series'.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

If you're using version `0.17.0` or higher then you can call this using [`.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas.Series.dt.strftime) which is vectorised:

```
all_data['Order Day new'] = all_data['Order Day new'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

** If your pandas version is older than `0.17.0` then you have to call `apply` and pass the data to `strftime`:

```
In [111]:

all_data = pd.DataFrame({'Order Day new':[dt.datetime(2014,5,9), dt.datetime(2012,6,19)]})
print(all_data)
all_data.info()
  Order Day new
0    2014-05-09
1    2012-06-19
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Order Day new    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 32.0 bytes

In [108]:

all_data['Order Day new'] = all_data['Order Day new'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
all_data
Out[108]:
  Order Day new
0    2014-05-09
1    2012-06-19
In [109]:

all_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Order Day new    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 32.0+ bytes
```

You can't call `strftime` on the column as it doesn't understand `Series` as a param hence the error

Comment: In pandas `1.0.5` this is producing a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Answer (score 34):

```
all_data['Order Day new']=all_data['Order Day new'].astype(str)
```

I think this is more simple, if the date is already in the format you want it in string form.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase not much to explain I think, just using the .astype method

Comment: Well, then explain why you've used it anyways. The accepted answer (that means: the one that solved the OP's problem) does not use it, and then you should explain what makes your solution better

Comment: @NicoHaase ok, added that its more simple

Comment: Do you **think** that or is that the case? Does it return the same value as `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`?

Comment: I checked it and yes

Comment: I like this answer, and it seems to work with NaT values in the column.

Answer (score 16):

For converting all datetime columns to string use the below code.

```
for x in  df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64']).columns.tolist():
    df[x] = df[x].astype(str)
```

or

```
date_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64']).columns.tolist()
df[date_columns] = df[date_columns].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a pySpark dataframe. This is how I converted "day" of type timestamp, to a string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
convertedDf = rawDf.withColumn('d2', F.date_format(rawDf['day'], 'yyyyMMdd'))
```