# How to do logical comparison to dataframe column value using cursor excute in pandas

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cursor

I have a dataframe (df) like below

```
df

MAX_TIMESTAMP   
2020-01-24 03:07:40
```

I want to pass a value from dataframe column and apply greater than comparison the below query.

My query

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM ofs.ord_add oa
        WHERE oa.is_active = 'Y' AND  CREATE_TIMESTAMP > '2020-01-20 08:23:12'""")

data=cursor.fetchall()
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
status = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

How can I replace the hardcorded value with a parameter value for datetime coming from a dataframe ?

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html replace the hardcoded value with a %s or %(sth)s and refer to that value with a tuple or dictionary.    create_timestamp > %(sth)s;""" {sth:sth}) the link should explain more

Comment: @sammywemmy, Can you write this as an answer as this will helpful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

I am referencing this link : [psycopg2 - usage](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html)  
 
Replace the hardcoded value with a %s or %(sth)s and refer to that value with a tuple or dictionary.

```
cursor.execute(
               """SELECT * FROM ofs.ord_add oa
                  WHERE oa.is_active = 'Y' AND  CREATE_TIMESTAMP > %(sth)s;
               """
               {sth:sth}
                )
```

the link should explain more

Answer (score 0):

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM ofs.ord_add oa WHERE oa.is_active = 'Y' AND  CREATE_TIMESTAMP > %s"
# Index is the df index of the value 
index = 0

cursor.execute(sql_query , (df["MAX_TIMESTAMP"].values[index]))
```

Comment: Hey, Its failing below error`DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Comment: Hi, the reason may be that in your df you have numpy datetime64 type but in db dates are in strings. Try to convert your date values into strings (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694025/converting-a-datetime-column-back-to-a-string-columns-pandas-python) and maybe be sure to send actual date values in tuple. Update me.

Comment: Still not working.In Db its a  `NOT NULL DATE ` date field and dataframe column I made it into datetime format using `pd.datetime'

Comment: So sorry to hear that, I'm suspecting a datetime type mismatch issue here, check this blog https://indradhanush.github.io/blog/dealing-with-datetime-objects-in-python/ I'm hoping this will help.