# How can write every date in x axis?

Tags: python-3.x, date, matplotlib, axis

Get stock `aaa` via web api:

```
import requests,json,time
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
ticker = 'aaa'
start_date='2020-01-01'
end_date='2023-05-10'
fd = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
td = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
data = requests.get('https://apipubaws.tcbs.com.vn/stock-insight/v1/stock/bars-long-term?ticker={}&type=stock&resolution=D&from={}&to={}'.format(ticker, fd, td)).json()
df = json_normalize(data['data'])
df['tradingDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.tradingDate.str.split("T", expand=True)[0])
df.columns = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'date']
```

Prepare x,y data for plotting:

```
x = df['date'][0:30]
y = df['close'][0:30]
```

Draw the graph:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

There are 30 dates in the raw data (x,y),`plt.show()` only draw part of date,how can draw all the 30 dates in x axis?

```
>>> min(x)
Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')
>>> max(x)
Timestamp('2020-02-19 00:00:00')
>>> len(x)
30
```

I want to write every date from `2020-01-02` till `2020-02-19` ,30 dates shown on the x axis.

Comment: Your data doesn't have a row for every calendar day (no data for maybe Saturday and Sunday)... are you expecting x-axis labels for all dates (every day from Jan 2nd to Feb 19th) or only the 30 entries for which data is available?

Comment: I want to write every date from 2020-01-02 till 2020-02-19 ,30 dates shown on the x axis.

Comment: If there is a ticklabel for **every day**, It will be ~50 ticklabels, not 30.... that was the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every calendar date to be shown, you can add these lines at the bottom. This will show each and every calendar date (50 entries)...

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import dates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=1))   #to get a tick every day
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))     #optional formatting 
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if you want to ONLY see the dates for which you have data in `x`, you need to add this line before `plt.show()` along with the code above. This will show the 30 entries....

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is better to convert the data type into string ,then show on x axis.

Comment: You can... but they would be equally spaced... here, the spaces between date will be set as per calendar dates

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timestamp into string and extract part of `xxxx-xx-xx`.

```
x=x.apply(lambda x:str(x)[0:10])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use above or use the python inbuilt function `strftime()`, which might be easier and safer. An example is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694025/converting-a-datetime-column-to-a-string-column)